# exif_imagetype() returning error on moving .gif (but still posts link to picture)

Tags: php, html, image

I've got a simple uploading script that works well for all file types (including non-moving .gif) that aren't moving .gifs. It uses exif_imagtype() to figure out whether or not a file is an image, then post a thumbnail or a text-link. The error I'm getting is:

> Attachments: Warning: exif_imagetype(uploads/waterbaloons.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/oversized_shirt/logbook/daily_log/whichposts.php on line 57 Warning: exif_imagetype(uploads/waterbaloons.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/oversized_shirt/logbook/daily_log/whichposts.php on line 60 **waterbaloons.gif**

I bolded the last part; after all those errors, it still posts a (working) link to the .gif file. Every other type of image does not return an error (again, including non-moving .gif). Here is the relevant code. $filenames is just an array of filename strings.

```
#Displays a text-link or a thumbnail 
        foreach ($filenames as $filename){
            $fileloc = "uploads/" . $filename;
            if (exif_imagetype($fileloc) != False){
                echo "<a href = '" .$fileloc. "'> <img src='" .$fileloc. "' height='150' width='150'></a>";
            }
            elseif (exif_imagetype($fileloc) == False){
                echo "<a href='" .$fileloc. "'>" .$filename. "</a> &nbsp";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could put '@' behind exif_imagetype(), but I'd like to know if there's anything I can do code-wise to stop this error. Is there, for example, a way of determining whether or not a .gif is a moving one? Or is there something just wrong w/ my code? *Or* is this just a job for a try-catch?

Comment: Update: Try/Catch does not catch this exception.